# How to run an exe in Visual Studio 2010 outside of the Output Directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I'm working on converting a project from Visual Studio 2008 to 2010 and came upon this issue.  All of the object files are dumped into the **Output Directory**, and the Executable is placed in a different folder that is kept cleaner.  The Executable's location and name are defined in the Linker Property **Output File**.

The project builds all the files just fine and in their appropriate places, however upon trying to run the program, it looks for the Exe in the **Output Directory** and fails.  This was not the case in 2008.

How do I tell VS where the executable is that it just made?

Comment: which language are you using??

Comment: Figured it out, I feel silly.

There is a separate field for the output of the obj files that was being set to the path of the **Output Directory**.  I can just change the field for **Object File Name** to point elsewhere and set my **Output Directory** to the same path as my exe.

Btw I'm using C++.

Comment: In which case, answer your own question with the above solution, and accept it - so others know what the answer is, without needing to look at comments.

Comment: I can't, not enough reputation :)
Need to wait a period of time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I feel silly.

There is a separate field for the output of the obj files that was being set to the path of the Output Directory. My Output Directory was also the same as the Intermediate Directory, as it was in 2008.

The Intermediate Directory should point to where you want your obj and other compilation files.  The Output Files should point to your Intermediate Directory.  And your exe should go to your Output Directory.  Simple enough!  The old project settings were throwing me off.